# PostgreSQL input bulk data While Skipping Relation Error

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

Im doing a bulk insert to PostgreSQL using PG_Admin tools, the table field `anamnesa_id` contain ForeignKey relation to other table `pasien_anamnesa`,

Is there a way to ignore or skip (**which is not exist in other table**) the error while inserting all the query? because deleting the error query 1 by 1 is just impossible for this many data (**25.000 records**),

i've trying:

```
INSERT INTO "pasien_item" ("id", "anamnesa_id") VALUES (1, 2) ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT pasien_item_pkey DO NOTHING;
```

resulting error:

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "pasien_item" violates foreign key constraint "pasien_item_anamnesa_id_dc66b31b_fk_pasien_anamnesa_id"
DETAIL:  Key (anamnesa_id)=(2) is not present in table "pasien_anamnesa".
SQL state: 23503
```

from that error i also tried:

```
INSERT INTO "pasien_item" ("id", "anamnesa_id") VALUES (1, 2) ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT pasien_item_anamnesa_id_dc66b31b_fk_pasien_anamnesa_id DO NOTHING;
```

resulting error:

```
ERROR:  constraint in ON CONFLICT clause has no associated index
SQL state: 42809
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON CONFLICT` can only deal with unique constraints, not foreign key or check constraints.

You need to rewrite your query to use a SELECT that only returns the rows where the foreign keys exist:

```
INSERT INTO pasien_item(id, anamnesa_id) 
select v.id, v.anamnesa_id
from (
   VALUES (1, 2), ...
) v(id, anamnesa_id) 
WHERE EXISTS (select *
              from pasien_anamnesa pa
              where pa.anamnesa_id = v.anamnesa_id)
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT pasien_item_pkey DO NOTHING;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=897e2647a6e9301a4aca29ec5d84e1f8)

Comment: ```ERROR:  syntax error at or near "v"
LINE 2: .1, 2) v(id, anam...
                       ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 315```

Comment: Well, obviously you need to replace the `...` part with the other rows you have

Comment: yeah i already did:
```INSERT INTO "pasien_item" ("id", "anamnesa_id", "DIAGNOSA") select v.id, v.anamnesa_id, v.DIAGNOSA from (VALUES (38410, 11732, 'OK') v(id, anamnesa_id, DIAGNOSA) WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from pasien_anamnesa pa where pa.anamnesa_id = v.anamnesa_id) ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT pasien_item_pkey DO NOTHING;```

Comment: It should have been `EXISTS` not `NOT EXISTS` but the syntax works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=897e2647a6e9301a4aca29ec5d84e1f8

Comment: ahh, i miss one closing bracket, now it worked! thanks man!

Comment: but its not working if value is null, i forgot to mention, if some record is Null https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=27f5098c3795db6f432d9b7a84f7039d

Comment: Then cast it `NULL::integer` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6619adbefb2554387c30e14f7a2976de - but you only need to do that if `null` is in the first row https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a60af14b4411c9bd0f0cfce5da5ed21f

Comment: what if there is no way to cast it to null record? since replacing ```Null``` with ```NULL::integer``` will also affected other ```Null``` record , even using regex replace is cannot be used in this case.

Comment: ah i found a way,  i just need to delete all the record, since data with id Null is unusable